# memtest86+: tracking down a parity error, smart ideas needed

Tags: memory, memtest86+, memory-error

Okay guys, I really hope someone smart will hint me towards the right solution. I got a HP Z420 Workstation and I've upgraded the memory. I had 4x4GB before and I bought additional 4x4GB. All 8x4GB are the same: "Samsung 2Rx8 PC3-12800E-11-11-E3". So there are 8 DIMM slots on my main board. Those DIMM slots are dual-channel. DIMM slots 1+3+6+8 are colored black (channel 1), DIMM slots 2+4+5+7 are colored white (channel 2). My old 4x4GB bars were inside the black channel 1 DIMM slots. I inserted the new 4x4GB bars into the white channel 2 DIMM slots. When running memtest, I end up with the message:

```
929-Fatal MCA error.
    HA error detected CPU 0 DIMM Slot 5 or 6
    Memory read error - DB parity error
```

After that I tried different configurations to track down the bug and I've reached a dead end where I need input from smart people :)
Here's a picture of my test summary with description below:
[image]

```
Column B: old bars inside the black channel 1, new bars inside the white channel 2. Fails with the message that I have posted earlier.

Column C: testing only the old bars with memtest, it works

Column D: testing only the new bars with memtest, it works. that "4 / 78%" means that I let memtest run until pass 4 at 78% before I stopped it. I forgot to document that at column C.
```

**important interim conclusion:** the old and the new memory bars both work! So there seems to be a problem when I mix them.

```
Column E: mixing 3 new and 1 old (only black / channel 1): works!

Column F: mixing old and new in dual channel slot 5+6: fails! (forgot to document the slots from the error message though, that's why there's only a red field without description)

Column G: mixing old and new in dual channel slot 3+4: fail!

Column H: mixing old and new in dual channel slot 1+2: fail!
```

**interim thoughts:** mixing old and new in dual channel always fails, so could it be that I need to put the old ones and the new ones into their own dual channels? shouldn't make a difference since all 8 bars have the same specs but it looks like it does.

```
Column I: swapping the bars between slot 2 and 3 from column H. So now the new bars are in the same dual channel: works! yay, my theory seems right.

Column J: group the new bars in a dual channel and group the old bars in a dual channel: fails againnnnnnn omg I want to cry ;_;
```

I have run out of ideas, I don't see any pattern in the error messages. Does anyone have a good idea / comment? I mean look at column C and D: all RAM bars are fine! then I mix then in columns F to H and they fail, but as soon as I mix them the "right way" it works (column I). But then again it doesn't (column J). What's going on here, I'm so clueless :/

Comment: Have you considered the problem is the motherboard not the memory?

Comment: Whenever you populate slots  2 or 4 (belonging to the same dual channel pair) you get errors - this looks like a dead channel. Try to populate ONLY 2 and 4, if it boots you can rule this out.

Comment: @Eugen: column F contradicts that idea, where 2 and 4 are empty but the error persists :/ and I don't think that loading only 2 and 4 is possible since those are channel 2 slots which are supposed to be only loaded if channel 1 is loaded, right?

Comment: @user3182532 Column F is a "no boot" condition, telling us nothing about the channel.

Comment: what do you mean it's a "no boot" condition? it did boot and I was able to start memtest? edit: oh you mean that configuration doesn't tell us anything about slot 2 and 4? but column I does!

Comment: Then you should say so more clearly in the Question! With most dual-channel boards, this would be a "no boot".

Comment: why would column F be a "no boot" with most dual channel boards?